# How do I get corner radius of drawable resource in runtime?

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I want to get the corner radius of a shape resource in run-time and scale the radius base on my conditions. Shape resource compile to 'GradientDrawable'. I can't find a function in 'GradientDrawable' to get corner radius.
For example consider a simple shape resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">    
    <solid android:color="#ff0000ff" />
    <corners android:radius="10px" />
</shape>
```

How do I get the corner radius of drawable resource in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that. You can only set it programmatically, you can't get the current value of it.

[`setCornerRadii`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setCornerRadii(float[]))

[`setCornerRadius`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setCornerRadius(float))

Comment: Starting from API 24, [`getCornerRadii()` and `getCornerRadius()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable) are available.